# Creating a read stream to a directory and piping entire directory to MongoDB Bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stream, fs

I am trying to save an entire directory to a **MongoDB Bucket**.

It works when I zip the file, but I need the files to be unzipped in the bucket.

When I try to stream the directory an error reads `"Illegal operation on a directory"`.

I've been trying to find a solution but cannot find one for a directory.

```
let conn = mongoose.connection;
let gfb;

conn.once('open', () => {
  //init the stream
  console.log('- Connection open -');
  gfb = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
    chunkSizeBytes: 1024,
    bucketName: 'uploads'
  })
})

const uploaddb = (req, res, vile) => {
conn.once('open', () => {
    console.log('- Connection open -');
    gfb = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
      chunkSizeBytes: 1024,
      bucketName: 'uploads'
    })
    try {
    uploadDir('/Users/nancycollins/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/unzipped/')
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  });
}

async function uploadDir (folder, subFolder = '') {
  const actualFolder = path.join(folder, subFolder)
  const contents = await fs.readdir(actualFolder, { withFileTypes: true })
  await Promise.all(contents.map((fileOrDirectory) =>
    fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()
      ? uploadDir(folder, path.join(subFolder, fileOrDirectory.name))
      : uploadFile(folder, path.join(actualFolder, fileOrDirectory.name))
  ))
}

async function uploadFile (baseFolder, filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .pipe(gfb.openUploadStream(filePath, { metadata: path.relative(baseFolder, filePath) }))
      .on('error', function(error) {
        reject(error);
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
        resolve()
      })
  })
}
```

-I have also tried change the try-catch to this:

```
    try {
    const folder = '/Users/nancycollins/virtuload-beta/backend/uploads/unzipped/';
    uploadDir(folder)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
```

EDIT:

This is the updated version.

The error currently reads:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1147:7)
```

etc...

Comment: You can't do that. You can `pipe` all the files in a directory, but not the directory itself.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I could create a directory in MongoDB and add the files to it? See the files will be html and js files so they need to keep their communication flow.

Comment: If you need to keep some structure you can upload the files and save their relative folder information in the [metadata](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#files.metadata) field.

Comment: I see, could you point me in the right direction to figure how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:**

Upload the folder files and keep their relative folder structure stored in GridFS's `metadata`. In this example `uploadDir` is a recursive function that goes through the given folder and its subfolders and calls `uploadFile` for every file found.

In this example I assume you are using a promisified version of [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).

```
async function uploadDir (folder, subFolder = '') {
  const actualFolder = path.join(folder, subFolder)
  const contents = await fs.readdir(actualFolder, { withFileTypes: true })
  await Promise.all(contents.map((fileOrDirectory) =>
    fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()
      ? uploadDir(folder, path.join(subFolder, fileOrDirectory.name))
      : uploadFile(folder, path.join(actualFolder, fileOrDirectory.name))
  ))
}

async function uploadFile (baseFolder, filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .pipe(gfb.openUploadStream(filePath, { metadata: path.relative(baseFolder, filePath) }))
      .on('error', function(error) {
        reject(error);
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
        resolve()
      })
  })
}
```

**Edit:**

If you don't need to store more info you can just set the GridFS file's `name` to be the relative path.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution thank you. When you say set the GridFS's file's name to be the relative path what do you mean?

Comment: I'm also getting the error:

"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object"

at "const actualFolder = path.join(folder, subFolder)"

Comment: I mean instead of doing `gfb.openUploadStream(filePath, ...` doing `gfb.openUploadStream(yourRelativePath...`. What is the first argument you are calling the function with? Can you update your question so we can check your new code?

Comment: Oh yes I assigned the value of the rel path to filePath. I have updated my code here with your suggestion implemented. I wrapped the whole thing in a try catch.

Comment: Mmm folder argument should be an absolute path. Also you just need to create both functions I posted in my answer and call `uploadDir('<absolutePath>')` from your original `uploaddb()` function. Then when the promise is resolved you can send the response to the client.

Comment: Oh I see! That's much better than the way I was trying. I have again edited my code, please see above.

Comment: I've tried it and works perfectly fine for me, maybe paste full stack trace? Also capture it with `uploadDir(folder).catch(console.error)`

Comment: It isn't giving an error and yet nothing is showing up in my MongoDB. 

Could you post your working version please so I can see where I'm going wrong? 

As if it is the same as my solution then there must be a deeper issue with my code.

Comment: Also how are you testing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199357/discussion-between-marcos-luis-and-nancy-collins).